# Around a theorem of Kronecker

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Hi,

let $k/\mathbb{Q}$ be a number field. Assume that $u$ is an algebraic integer such that all $k$-conjugates have modulus $1$. Is $u$ a root of $1$ ?

If $k=\mathbb{Q}$, the answer is YES (this is Kronecker's theorem). I am pretty sure that this result is false if $k$ is an arbitrary number field, but I don't see any obvious counter-example.

Any suggestion ?

Thanks!

Comment: If $u\in k$ and $k$ is Galois over $\bf Q$, then this is true. See Lemma 1.6 in Washington, "Introduction to cyclotomic fields".

Comment: You should register an account to prevent duplicate identities.

Answer (score 4):

The answer depends on the number field $k$. Of course, it cannot hold for all fields $k$, for if $u$ is an algebraic integer of modulus $1$  which is not a root of unity (there are plenty of them, see e.g. [this MO-link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38680/can-an-algebraic-number-on-the-unit-circle-have-a-conjugate-with-absolute-value-d)), then set $k=\mathbb Q(u)$, so $u$ is the only $k$-conjugate of $u$.