# Algebraic integer with conjugates on the unit circle

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\alpha$ be an algebraic integer on the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$ such that all the conjugates of $\alpha$ lie on the unit circle. Does it follow that $\alpha$ is a root of unity?

Comment: Yes; see Mark Sapir's answer to this question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/38680/can-an-algebraic-number-on-the-unit-circle-have-a-conjugate-with-absolute-value

Comment: It is called Kronecker's theorem.

Comment: @AndreasThom Could you please give a reference to a book or paper where it is called Kronecker's theorem?

Comment: The original reference is [L.Kronecker, Zwei Sätze über Gleichungen mit ganzzahligen Coefficienten, J. Reine u. Angew. Math. 53, (1857), 173-175.]

Comment: Since the product of norms of $\alpha$ over various completions is 1, it has to be a algebraic unit. Then it follows that the cyclic subgroup $C$ generated by $\alpha$ is bounded for every norm. Since $\mathbf{Z}[\alpha^{\pm 1}]$ is discretely embedded as a subring in some finite product of completions, we deduce that $C$ is finite.

Comment: See Theorem 8 in Section IV.4 of Weil: Basic number theory. I mention this as the proof here is very transparent: it relies on the fact that the intersection of a compact set and a discrete set is finite.

Comment: The same is true of $\alpha^k$ and the characteristic polynomials of the $\alpha^k$ have coeffts that are bounded indept of $k$. A lot of them must be equal to each other, so $\alpha^k = \alpha^\ell$ for some $k$ and $\ell$.